# Asp.net core localization - how to pass to translators if there's no default resource

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, localization

I studied the [new approach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization) to localization in ASP.Net Core about using `IStringLocalizer` and using it like `_localizer["About Title"]`.

Then it's also stated that

> For many developers the new workflow of not having a default language
>   .resx file and simply wrapping the string literals can reduce the
>   overhead of localizing an app.

It does reduce the overhead, but what will I pass to translators then? usually, I have a default `Resource.resx` which is in english, which they are able to translate and give me back `Resource.fr.resx`. What's the workflow with the new "not having a default language .resx" mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit late, but here's the answer if you still need it. You could have a file named `YourResource.en-US.resx` or `YourResource.en.resx` and set it up like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    // Your resources folder
    services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    ...
    // Languages you support in your application
    var supportedCultures = new[]
    {
        new CultureInfo("en-US"),
        new CultureInfo("xx-YY")
    };

    app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
    {
        // default language
        DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-US", "en-US");,
        SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
        SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
    });
}
```

Then you send the `YourResource.en-US.resx` file to your translators. By setting it up like showed above you're defining that file as your default (fallback if the right file is not available).

Comment: Well, you *can*. But what is the point of having the strings in the default language embedded in source code if you then anyway have to (manually) create a resource file containing those strings? That creates overhead instead of reducing, and how do you ensure that you don't forget to add new strings to that resource file. Impossible! I assume the real answer is to have a build-time tool to extract the embedded strings from the source code, but it's weird how that MS article offers nothing and even says absolutely *nothing* about how to work efficiently with this.